# Send downloaded page url on email and open this url in same window

Tags: php, file, email, download

I have `download.php` file:

```
 $file = // path to file 


    if ( file_exists($file) ) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.csv'); 
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($file);


        exit;
    }
```

So, if open `http://mysite.com/download.php`, `csv` file is downloaded.

I want sent this url on email, for this I do:

```
    $to = // recipient
    $title = // msg title
    $download_url = 'http://mysite.com/download.php';
    $msg = 'some text <a href="'.$download_url.'" target="_self">download file</a>';

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

    mail($to, $title, $msg, $headers);
```

My problems is this:   when click "download file" link (in email message), is opened another window in browser.

Question: there is possible to not open another, but stay same window and so download file?

Answer (score 0):

I think, this will be handled by your webclient (like outlook). You have no influence of visitors mailclient.